# Webkitgtk build error

Tags: webkit

When I use  `./configure` or `./autogen.sh` for configuring webkit after installing dependencies it shows this type of error:

```
checking for LIBSOUP... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libsoup-2.4 >= 2.37.2.1) were not met:

Requested 'libsoup-2.4 >= 2.37.2.1' but version of libsoup is 2.4.0

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBSOUP_CFLAGS
and LIBSOUP_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I've also try it with libsoup-2.36, but it gives error also and when I update libsoup from 2.36 to 2.4.0 or 2.4.1, problem is not resolved.
I've googled it lot, also configure pkg-config and ld_library path.
but it gives error on both of my system i.e. fedora 16 and ubuntu 11.10
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is quite clear - you need newer libsoup version!